# how to change order of parent options shown in help screen?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have the following Python 3 code:

```
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='my-prog')
common_optional_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)
common_optional_parser.add_argument('--foo', help='help for --foo')
common_optional_parser.add_argument('--bar', help='help for --bar')
subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(dest='subcmd', required=True)
my_sub_parser1 = subparsers.add_parser('abc', help='help for abc',
                                       parents=[common_optional_parser])
my_sub_parser1.add_argument('--suboption', help='help for suboption', action='store_true')
my_sub_parser1.set_defaults(func=some_func)
args = main_parser.parse_args()
```

When I run it, I see:

```
$ ./my-prog.py abc -h
usage: my-prog abc [-h] [--foo FOO] [--bar BAR] [--suboption]

options:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
  --foo FOO    help for --foo
  --bar BAR    help for --bar
  --suboption  help for suboption
```

Is it possible to show the `--suboption` line above the common options (`--foo` and `--bar`), as well as show the `--help` option last?

Thanks

Comment: order is determined by the order they were added to the parser, and parent's are added first.

Comment: you might want to put the parent's arguments in an argument group, ArgumentParser.add_argument_group(title=None